# Staging using gerrit?

Tags: deployment, staging, gerrit

I would like to use gerrit to handle the staging steps, something like this

- push
- review by developer
- button "merge to testing"
- e.g. client side testing
- button "merge testing to master"

It seems there is already everything in place to do so: http://developer.qt.nokia.com/uploads/gerrit/3_4_3_pushing_updated_change.png

How do I need to set my gerrit up to behave this way?

Answer (score 1):

That seems like a custom patched Gerrit installation at Nokia. In the public available Gerrit package you cannot merge to a staging branch.

Answer (score 1):

We are merging into a code reviewed devel branch that is built onto a testing server. Jenkins does the builds of that devel branch and builds the changes that go into refs/for/devel for code review.

Testing is done separately and documented, though arguably this process is less controlled than the code review but it works well nonetheless as we're doing quite a bit of ad hoc testing prior to code review, along with JUnit tests.

I guess there are many tools to manage QA, though this is the first I see of gerrit being used for managing testing.